# How to fix vague ASP.NET runtime error that killed intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So I was running both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 on my computer but removed 2019 yesterday due to disk space issues. Now on all of my aspx and ascx files I'm getting "ASP.NET Runtime error:" and warnings under all ASP.NET controls for both C# and vb.net that says the controls haven't been declared. Websites run locally without issue, but intellisense is gone and my server-side code is being treated as a text file by the editor which is a pain for coding. I'm using .NET framework (I know it's old, but it's for work).
I've installed all the targeting packs for it from 4.0 onwards which VS 2019 took with it. I've also restarted the computer and tried repairing visual studio. I'm not sure what else to try. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe reinstall Visual Studio 2022 (not 2019 of course) again, or repair installation? _Edit:_ And be aware of what is selected and what is not, in the 2022 installation. Select too little, and some of your uses will no longer work; select too much and you may have disk space issues again.

Comment: Does it build? Usually building mine or waiting a while resurrects my intellisense on a similar project

Comment: Do a clean build.  Intermediate obj files are still referencing the old Net version and the compiler dependencies to not recognize a change in Net versions.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled vs2022. My iis website does build, but that doesn't fix the problem. I can't debug, use intellisense, or features like bulk commenting and formatting.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See can I answer my own question.., Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2019, and that some how fixed the problem.